# combining small nested/unnested json files

Tags: json, parquet

i am trying to find ways to combine  multiple small json files of 1 or 2 kbs or so . the data is in the form of a json file that has multiple records in  nested or unnested forms . the s3 bucket which has the data has the following folder structure :

```
mybucket --
             |__mainfolder--
                    |___dateid=2019folder
                            |___acctid=239828folder
                                     |___testfolder
                                            |__test1folder
                                                 |____file1.json
                                                 |____file2.json 


|__mainfolder--
                |___dateid=2019folder
                            |___acctid=458398folder
                                     |___testfolder
                                            |__test2folder
                                                 |____file1.json
                                                 |____file2.json 
                                            |___test3folder
                                                  |__file3.json
                                                  |__file4.json
```

here in the s3 bucket , i have a mainfolder which has partitions by dateid, acctid,testfolder,testfolder.the s3 bucket which has a mainfolder in which i have folder each for each date . if you go into one of the date folder you will see folders for all the accountids one each . if you go into any of the accountid folders you will see some performance testing folder in which is the actual json. as shown above in the bucket structure in one test folder there could be different kinds of test1folder,test2folder etc each runs different kinds of tests .all the files are small in single digit kbs mostly , sometimes a little big. this s3 data is taken into athena (presto) ddl in hive . and compression format to be used is parquet. before i implement parquet , i want to combine these small files into one large file and then compress using parquet. i am trying to combine all the test result json files from all the accounts for one date for one type of test . So it would be combining a huge number of small files . i tried s3distcp on emr but it did not help .i am not sure of my script was right . 
to improve the performance of athena , partitions are being reduced as well but right now combining small files is what i cant figure out .

if any one can help me with any ideas that would be great. thanks

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thank you @GillesQuenot for fixing the view above  ..i will go through the document .